# Store data from image in a cookie

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am trying to store image in a cookie, but I don't know if this is the best way keep registers from a user when he refreshes the page.

Well, I am using ngCookies module to do that. So I received a image from server in base64 string format, the contentType and the data and then I store in the cookies:

```js
$cookies.contentType = value.image.contentType;

$cookies.data = value.image.data;
```

To make my url I do this:

```js
vm.url = "data:"+vm.value.image.contentType+";base64,"+vm.value.image.data;
```

And the url I insert in my page, using img html:

```html
<img src={{ctrl.url}} style="width:200px;height:200px">
```

My problem is: when I refreshed my page, $cookies.contentType remains, but value.data doesn't stay stored in $cookies.data anymore. I think this value is too big to store in a cookie. I am using cookies correctly? Are there other way to do that?

I appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: That's actually amazing!! Image data is far too long to be stored as a cookie (limit is around 4kb)! Still, impressive that's you'd even dare to do that :p

Comment: Would you care about using LocalStorage for this usage ?

Comment: Now I am using localStorage and it's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cookies for client side storage is generally considered to be [less than ideal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies). Cookies are automatically sent back with every request (if it matches domain/path/security restrictions). Even if the cookie storage limit could handle this I can't imagine you would want to send this back with any future request. [LocalStorage and similar technologies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) were developed in part to avoid this issue.

That said, the [http cookie spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) originally stated that a cookie needed to [accommodate at least 4096 bytes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-6.1) which was then generally interpreted as setting a max size of approximately 4k. Each browser handles this a bit differently and there are plenty of [places to read up on it](https://www.google.com/search?q=http%20cookie%20size%20limit).

Comment: Thanks for your help. You're right. 

Now I am using this module([link](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)) and everything is working. 

Best regards